# Split report line across pages in Odoo qweb report

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

Looking for a solution to break a report line across pages in qweb report. Here is the situation, i have long product decription and it needs to be splited between pages and not to be moved (whole line) to the next page. It should look like this:

```html
Page 1
__________________________
1. | Product | Description |
2. | Product | Description |
3. | Product | Long descip |
.. | ....... | tion long l |

Page 2
__________________________
.. |.........| ong descript|
.. |.........| ion         | 
4. | Prodcut | Description |
...
```

What i tried so far is to comment all css, less files lines which included:
 tr, td {page-break-inside: avoid}

Also tried to apply my apply own style to tr and td elements:

{ page-break-inside:auto!important;}

Nothing worked so far. All that page spliting is done by wkhtmltopdf, maybe its limitation on that side? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you